# Curl download speed restricted when down/uploading from stdin/stdout

Tags: files, curl, stdout, stdin, stderr

I'm running 2 curl commands where one downloads all the data into stdout/in until the stack is filled and another uploading whatever is in it out but it seems like the speed is restricted. For the task I'm doing I require it to write into stdin/out as I don't want to write into the disk. Is there a way to delimit the transfer speed?

`curl -w "%{stderr}%{size_download}:%{speed_download}\n" -s http://...someurl... -o /dev/stdout 2>output.txt | curl -s -w "%{stderr}%{size_upload}:%{speed_upload}\n" -T - http://...someurl... -o /dev/null 2>>output.txt`

output.txt is

`96912152:25781365,000`

`96925509:25373169,000`

however, if I run just the download and have it actually save the file

`curl -w "%{stderr}%{size_download}:%{speed_download}\n" -s -O http://...someurl...  -o /dev/stdout 2>output.txt`

output.txt is

`96912152:95952625,000`

EDIT:

I've tried adding the `--no-buffer` flag to the first command it made no difference in `%{speed_download}`

Comment: The manpage mentions that there is a buffer involved for both stdin and stdout. The `--no-buffer` option can turn off the stdout buffer, so can you try that and see if the `speed_download` value changes for the first command?

Comment: @Haxiel Just tried adding the `--no-buffer` flag and the results were still similar to the first output. This is what I ran `curl --no-buffer -w "%{stderr}%{size_download}:%{speed_download}\n" -s http://...someurl... -o /dev/stdout 2>output.txt | curl -s -w "%{stderr}%{size_upload}:%{speed_upload}\n" -T - http://...someurl... -o /dev/null 2>>output.txt
`